# Is it possible to make outputs on command prompts different colors? C# programming

Tags: c#, console-application

Let's say you want to write a program in C# and compile it with command prompt. Assume the simple program only says;

```
 Console.WriteLine("a" + "b" + "c" + "d");
```

Is it possible to make a, b, c, d print out in different colors on command prompt?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937256/changing-text-color-in-c-sharp-console-application  But you'll need to Write each after changing the color and WriteLine on the "d".

Answer (score 2):

yes. you must change the color and print your text like:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
Console.WriteLine("a");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.WriteLine("b");
.
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Console.ForegroundColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor.aspx) property with [`ConsoleColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecolor.aspx) enumeration.

> Gets or sets the foreground color of the console.

Like;

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        string a = "a";
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        string b = "b";
        Console.WriteLine(b);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
        string c = "c";
        Console.WriteLine(c);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        string d = "d";
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }
```

Output will be;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `Console` class has the `ForegroundColor` property that you can use:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.Write(a);
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.Write(b);
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.Write(c);
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
Console.WriteLine(d);
```