# C# library for more ConsoleColors?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, windows-console

I have been writing console apps for a while and noticed that the consoles (such as cmd.exe)  support RGB colors but the 'Console' class for .NET doesn't. Does anyone know of a library that would allow RGB colors for a console app in C#?

Comment: You mean outside of 16 colors ([ConsoleColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecolor.aspx) ) ? Please show a sample what you are talking about than.

Comment: yes other than colors in `ConsoleColor`. I want to be able to set the `Console.Foreground` color to a color with an specific RGB value.

Comment: Than please give a link / name a program that does that... because MSDN does not exactly agrees with your statement see - [SetConsoleTextAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: right click command prompt shortcut, go to colors tab, RGB values are an option.

Comment: just found out this can be done with any shortcut to a console app, so why cant it be done programmatically? Seems like it should be possible...

Comment: I think your question already has been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937256/changing-text-color-in-c-sharp-console-application

Comment: So it looks like Patrik found the duplicate question that contains the answer how to customize 16 colors. If you need more than 16 colors at a time - you need to specify it in your question (along with sample console program that does it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937256/changing-text-color-in-c-sharp-console-application) but it is not worth the time and effort, this should be easier to do and i hope that in future versions of .NET framework this process will be simplified.