# Cmd commands in C#

Tags: c#, cmd, command, prompt, text-based

I'm writing a small text-based adventure in C# that uses the command prompt for everything, and I'm looking for a way to change the colour of outputted text. None of the methods I've looked at have worked properly.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Tried this one? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937256/changing-text-color-in-c-sharp-console-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
```

Should work fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Couldn't find that anywhere... Probably wasn't trying hard enough though.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.WriteLine("blue.");
```

Read more about [`Console.ForegroundColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor.aspx) you can also change background of text: [`Console.BackgroundColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.backgroundcolor.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

What you looking for is [`Console.BackgroundColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.backgroundcolor.aspx) and [`Console.ForegroundColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor.aspx) properties.

For example;

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.WriteLine("This is blue!!");
```

[image]