# How to get foreground color from hex code in C#?

Tags: c#, colors, console-application

```
    using System;
    class ColorTheText
    {
        public static void Main(string [] args)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("\t\tCongratulations! You have cleared this level. \n\n\t\t\t    Entering Level 2...");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        }
    }
```

But I want to get the color from hex code i.e. ConsoleColor. color from hex code (#c0c0c0). How to do it?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937256/changing-text-color-in-c-sharp-console-application) says "No hex allowed" for ConsoleColor

Comment: error CS0117: 'System.ConsoleColor' does not contain a
        definition for 'silver' or 'Silver'

Comment: @Jonesy That is true. But it is possible.

Comment: There are only 16 possible colors so you could just hard-code the Color to ConsoleColor mapping with a switch() statement.  Do note that the names don't necessarily match the actual color that the user sees.  The console window allows remapping the color index to another color.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#c0c0c0");
```

Something like that is what you need?
Perhaps you serve.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: That will return `Color` instead of `ConsoleColor` which is required

Comment: You have reason, sorry.