# multiple colors on one line in console

Tags: c#

i'm working on a project, and for that i want to display if the CPU architecture is 64 or 32 bit. Now, i already have that:

```
 bool is64 = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem;
 if (is64) { Console.WriteLine("Architecture: 64 bit"); }
 else { Console.WriteLine("Architecture: 32 bit"); }
```

But i want to display the "Architecture" white, and the 64 bit or 32 bit part of the line green. is that possible? if so, i would appreciate it if I get an example of how to do it.

EDIT

people misunderstand this question. i mean something like this:

[image]

Anyone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom text color in C# console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937256/custom-text-color-in-c-sharp-console-application)

Comment: See the definition of `ConsoleColor` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolecolor?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

You set the color to `White` then Use `Console.Write` to output "Architecture".
Then, Set the color to `Green` and use `Console.WriteLine` to output the bit part.

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
Console.Write("Architecture: ");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
bool is64 = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem;
if (is64) { Console.WriteLine("64 bit"); }
else { Console.WriteLine("32 bit"); }
```

You might want save the original `ForegroundColor` aside, so you can restore it after.

Comment: Hey, thanks! i already thought of this, but can you look at the image above? thats what i mean

Comment: So? The technique is the same.. I don't see where you are stuck?