# How do I change the Color in a Method while using return

Tags: c#, colors

I want to change the Color before

```
$"Abteilung        { _name}
```

to like Red and then change it back to some other color

My code for that part.

```
public string AsString()
        {
  return
            $"{Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red}" +
            $"Abteilung        { _name}\n" +
            $"{Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue}" +
            $"Flaeche          {_flaeche} m2\n" +
            $"Abteilungsleiter {_abteilungsleiter.Vorname} {_abteilungsleiter.Nachname}\n" +
            $"Angestellte      {angestellte}\n" +
            $"Artikel          {ausgabeArtikel}\n";
        }
```

Its changing the Color but for all text and it does this:
I dont want like RedAbteilung and BlueFlaeche

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The coloring part happens at the time you output the display. You could create a small class that encapsulates a `Text` property and a `ConsoleColor` property, and then a method that interprets a collection of that class. Would that work?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937256/custom-text-color-in-c-sharp-console-application if you’re looking for a way to embed codes on strings and change the console colors. Only works on recent windows 10 though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $"{Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red}"

While it might be legal to perform an assignment of console color inside an interpolation break, it perhaps isn’t what you want because the assignment returns the value assigned which will then be captured into the String and printed. You need to split your statements up:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.Write("this is red");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.Write(" and this is blue");
```

If you’re looking for some dynamism to this,perhaps like Rufus commented:

```
var msgs = new List<(ConsoleColor C, string S)>();
msgs.Add((ConsoleColor.Red, "it’s red"));
msgs.Add((ConsoleColor.Blue, "it’s blue"));
```

Then later

```
foreach(var msg in msgs){
    Console.ForegroundColor = msg.C;
    Console.Write(msg.S);
}
```

I also linked something of a duplicate in the comments, if you're looking for a way to print e.g. `Console.Write("\x1b[48;5;1mit's red!\x1b[48;5;4mit's blue!")` - there is some p/invoke work to do first. Perhaps some library that already does this would suit you..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot accomplish this with a `ToString()` override unless you are willing to a) include some kind of markup in the returned value itself, and b) write additional code to interpret that markup when displaying the string.

For example, something like this:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A { Name = "name1", Text = "this is the object text" };

        WriteLineWithColor(a.ToString());
    }

    static void WriteLineWithColor(string textWithMarkup)
    {
        ConsoleColor previousColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
        int lastIndex = 0;

        try
        {
            foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(textWithMarkup, @"\[(?<color>.+?)\]"))
            {
                Console.Write(textWithMarkup.Substring(lastIndex, match.Index - lastIndex));

                if (Enum.TryParse<ConsoleColor>(match.Groups["color"].Value, out ConsoleColor color))
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = color;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(match.Value);
                }

                lastIndex = match.Index + match.Length;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(textWithMarkup.Substring(lastIndex));
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = previousColor;
        }
    }
}

class A
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
    public string Text { get; init; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"[Red]{Name} [Blue]{Text}";
    }
}
```

Outlook looks like this:

[image: red text and blue text]

As of Windows 10, the command prompt console now supports VT100 "smart terminal" color codes, which is a variation on the above theme. See e.g. [this answer to Custom text color in C# console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43321133). You still need to include the markup in the returned string (which makes it less useful for display in other contexts, like in the debugger) but it is the same sort of approach as above and doesn't require additional code to actually process the string.