# C# Convert System.ConsoleColor to System.Drawing.Color

Tags: c#, colors

Coming from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29192463/5201815) i would like to know if there is a easy way to reverse this method

```
public static System.ConsoleColor FromColor(System.Drawing.Color c)
{
    int index = (c.R > 128 | c.G > 128 | c.B > 128) ? 8 : 0; // Bright bit
    index |= (c.R > 64) ? 4 : 0; // Red bit
    index |= (c.G > 64) ? 2 : 0; // Green bit
    index |= (c.B > 64) ? 1 : 0; // Blue bit
    return (System.ConsoleColor)index;
}
```

into

```
public static System.Drawing.Color FromColor( System.ConsoleColor c)
{
    // ??
}
```

Comment: Did you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092421/convert-consolecolor-to-color Although its in VB.NET but should give you a clue!

Answer (score 6):

i made a answer out of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28211539/5201815), because values between the names of Color and ConsoleColor are different

```
public static System.Drawing.Color FromColor(System.ConsoleColor c)
{
    int[] cColors = {   0x000000, //Black = 0
                        0x000080, //DarkBlue = 1
                        0x008000, //DarkGreen = 2
                        0x008080, //DarkCyan = 3
                        0x800000, //DarkRed = 4
                        0x800080, //DarkMagenta = 5
                        0x808000, //DarkYellow = 6
                        0xC0C0C0, //Gray = 7
                        0x808080, //DarkGray = 8
                        0x0000FF, //Blue = 9
                        0x00FF00, //Green = 10
                        0x00FFFF, //Cyan = 11
                        0xFF0000, //Red = 12
                        0xFF00FF, //Magenta = 13
                        0xFFFF00, //Yellow = 14
                        0xFFFFFF  //White = 15
                    };
    return Color.FromArgb(cColors[(int)c]);
}
```

Patrick Hofmann's answer works aswell but produces invalid colors!

```
public static System.Drawing.Color FromColor(System.ConsoleColor c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case ConsoleColor.DarkYellow:
            return Color.FromArgb(255, 128, 128, 0);
        default:
            return Color.FromName(c.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to do a reverse function, it will be:

```
public static System.Drawing.Color FromColor(System.ConsoleColor c)
{
    int cInt = (int) c;

    int brightnessCoefficient = ((cInt & 8) > 0) ? 2 : 1;
    int r = ((cInt & 4) > 0) ? 64 * brightnessCoefficient : 0;
    int g = ((cInt & 2) > 0) ? 64 * brightnessCoefficient : 0;
    int b = ((cInt & 1) > 0) ? 64 * brightnessCoefficient : 0;

    return Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
}
```

Note: since `ConsoleColor` is an enum, it allows you to represent much lower range of colors. It means that when you convert `Color` to `ConsoleColor`, you cut off some information; and when you convert `ConsoleColor` to `Color`, you will need to restore it. In my implementation this function will set a color component value equal to 64 for dark colors, and 128 for bright colors. However, it may actually be another and may vary for different colors.

The best solution is actually to do a big `switch` statement with hardcoded colors.

Answer (score 2):

Converted to C# from [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092421/convert-consolecolor-to-color), which answers your question, but is in VB.NET (just posting for completeness):

```
static class ColorExtension
{
    public static Color DrawingColor(ConsoleColor color)
    {
        switch (color) {
            case ConsoleColor.Black:

                return Color.Black;
            case ConsoleColor.Blue:

                return Color.Blue;
            case ConsoleColor.Cyan:

                return Color.Cyan;
            case ConsoleColor.DarkBlue:

                return Color.DarkBlue;
            case ConsoleColor.DarkGray:

                return Color.DarkGray;
            case ConsoleColor.DarkGreen:

                return Color.DarkGreen;
            case ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta:

                return Color.DarkMagenta;
            case ConsoleColor.DarkRed:

                return Color.DarkRed;
            case ConsoleColor.DarkYellow:

                return Color.FromArgb(255, 128, 128, 0);
            case ConsoleColor.Gray:

                return Color.Gray;
            case ConsoleColor.Green:

                return Color.Green;
            case ConsoleColor.Magenta:

                return Color.Magenta;
            case ConsoleColor.Red:

                return Color.Red;
            case ConsoleColor.White:

                return Color.White;
            default:
                return Color.Yellow;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the names are equal but the values are different  as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28211539/5201815

Comment: Okay, but do you want to have the logical conversion or the technical conversion?

Comment: a correct convertion. the duplicate marked answer doesn't contain a correct answer with code

Comment: @PatrickHofman:- I think you can keep it as it is answering the intended question! +1