# PowerShell get default foreground color for write-host

Tags: powershell

I have a function to write an output log to file and to console. The Write-Host part I'd like to color up a bit ;-)

```
switch($logLevel)
{
   "FATAL" { $ConsoleWriteColor = "blue"; break }
   "ERROR" { $ConsoleWriteColor = "red"; break }
   "WARN" { $ConsoleWriteColor = "yellow"; break }
   default { $ConsoleWriteColor = "white"; break }

}
Write-Host -ForegroundColor $ConsoleWriteColor "Hello world"
```

So my question is for the default case: How can I get the current foreground color? I guess it will not always be white?!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Current foreground and background can be obtained like this.

```
PS>(get-host).ui.rawui.ForegroundColor
Gray
PS>(get-host).ui.rawui.BackgroundColor
Black
```

Comment: This always returns -1 for me?!

Comment: @silent You are in PowerShell ISE correct? This command will work in the native shell. Try it there

Comment: Yeah you are right... there is does work, but it says DarkYellow when the text is clearly in white?!

Comment: Looks like DarkYellow is missnamed. It is discussed here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21941606/why-does-powershell-display-darkyellow-text-improperly

Comment: Oh dear :) thanks, so I guess the answer is ok after all

Comment: When I run this in the Powershell ISE (v5.1.14409.1012), it returns `-1`, which does not cast to a `[System.ConsoleColor]`. That means that this would fail: `Write-Host -ForegroundColor ([System.ConsoleColor]-1) "Hello world"`

Answer (score 6):

To retrieve the foreground color in PowerShell, I found this command to work:

**[System.Console]::ForegroundColor**

Tested on:

- Win  7: ISE and native shell
- Win 10: ISE and native shell
- Win 11: ISE, native shell and terminal

(*Edited for clarity*)

Comment: [ForegroundColor methods no longer effective in PowerShell v7.2.6 #17886](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17886)

Comment: @joharr I believe the point of the question was getting the current value, not setting it. as far as I can tell from what I have tested that functionality still works.