# Change ConsoleColor to a hex value

Tags: c#, .net, colors, background, console

So I recently started learning C#, and I'm struggling to change background color of a console to a hex value. Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace MyFisrtC_App
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConsoleColor BGColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            ConsoleColor FGColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

            Console.Title = "Dumb App";
            Console.BackgroundColor = BGColor;
            Console.ForegroundColor = FGColor;

            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("This is just a simple dumb app. There is nothing special about it.");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Also if you know how to change font in C# that would be pretty cool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible due to the restriction of the Console API.

But you can for example calculate the nearest color to one that exist in the API.

```
static ConsoleColor ClosestConsoleColor(byte r, byte g, byte b)
{
    ConsoleColor ret = 0;
    double rr = r, gg = g, bb = b, delta = double.MaxValue;

    foreach (ConsoleColor cc in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor)))
    {
        var n = Enum.GetName(typeof(ConsoleColor), cc);
        var c = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(n == "DarkYellow" ? "Orange" : n); // bug fix
        var t = Math.Pow(c.R - rr, 2.0) + Math.Pow(c.G - gg, 2.0) + Math.Pow(c.B - bb, 2.0);
        if (t == 0.0)
            return cc;
        if (t < delta)
        {
            delta = t;
            ret = cc;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This is from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12340136/10315352 credits all to @Glenn

Comment: I mean, it was the closest one to what I was trying to achieve. But I realized that you actually cant use hex values or any other colors than one in ConsoleColor

Answer (score 0):

ConsoleColour is an enum which essentially is a list of numbers with defined names. So you can do the below to convert a number to a color

```
        int number = 7;
        ConsoleColor colour = (ConsoleColor)number;
```

If you want to do it from hex use the below

```
string hex = "0A";
int number = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
ConsoleColor colour = (ConsoleColor)number;
```

You just need to make sure the number doesnt fall outside of the length of the enum, for example

```
if(number < Enum.GetValues<ConsoleColor>().Length -1 && number >= 0)
{
   Console.ForeGroundColor = (ConsoleColor)number;
}
```

Comment: That will turn number to a colour, but how can I get it working with whole hex values?

Comment: @IKDev Ive updated my code to include converting a hex value to an int

Comment: Does it allow you to use hex values only of allready exsisting console colors or will it work with custom hex values too?

Comment: Notice, the "hex" in this answer has nothing to do with writing a RGB (255, 255, 255) value as Hex (FFFFFF) - as the answer tried to explain the `ConsoleColor` is an `enum`, any `enum` can be casted to an `integer`, and this answer shows you how to convert a `hex` to an `integer` and that again to the `enum`.

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can only use the colours exposed by this enum. There may well be a Pinvoke to allow RGB colours but im not too sure.

Comment: There is a Pinvoke, https://stackoverflow.com/a/43321133/12429913

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;

namespace TestCSharp
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("background red and text white");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.WriteLine("Color reset");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

you can't use hex value, you can use these color:

Black,
DarkBlue,
DarkGreen,
DarkCyan,
DarkRed,
DarkMagenta,
DarkYellow,
Gray,
DarkGray,
Blue,
Green,
Cyan,
Red,
Magenta,
Yellow,
White

Comment: Well thats sad, that you cant use hex values