# Convert color integer to text?

Tags: android, colors

I need to convert a color integer value back to text? For example, look at this imaginative code

```
int myColor = -16777216; //int value for Color.BLACK
convertColorToText(myColor);
```

The method would return string with value "BLACK".

Is this possible and how to do it?

---

**UPDATE**

My app uses a Color Picker (code.google.com/p/android-color-picker) and I want to notify user which color has he chosen. For example, he chooses a black color, clicks OK button, and sees a `Toast` saying "You have chosen Black color".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do it out-of-the-box, best what you can do is to build a map or list of known colors (for example using  'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'lightgray', 'darkgray' -> standard android colors understood by parseColor method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String)

And then you could find it by lookup and either exact match (but the usefulness of this would be limited) or finding the CLOSEST color. You can find out about a good and simplest algorithm of finding best match here, for example: [Best algorithm for matching colours.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678457/best-algorithm-for-matching-colours)

Comment: I want to notify a user which color has he selected. If he selects black, then I want him to see "You have selected a black color". He chooses color from a Color Picker project (http://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/)

Comment: so you need to build the mapping as I explained above - maybe you need to add more various colours, but it would work fine (you just need to have a map of RGB->color name and find the closest match).

Comment: I'd add that this color picker makes it easy for you to get the hue, which is the simplest value to get the color.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will try this and let you know of result.