# How can I get the colors hex code from custom colors.xml that I used on a View object?

Tags: android, xml, colors

So I have custom colors.xml:

```
<color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
<color name="pink">#FF00FF</color>
<color name="red">#FF0000</color>
....................
```

If I used a color on an object (i.e. View) to color its background how can I get back the hex code what is in the tags?
I mean I colored the view with yellow and I would like to know what hex code has that object -> #FFFF00

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RelativeLayout re=(RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.idStack);
ColorDrawable colorDrawable=(ColorDrawable)re.getBackground();
String hexcolor=Integer.toHexString(colorDrawable.getColor());
```

hexcolor -> FFFF00

**UPDATE**

In order to get the name of the color (#ff0000->RED), assuming that you're not doing anything too complicated since you provided that `color.xml` example in your question you should do this:

```
//Create a map of the colors you'll need
Map<Integer,String> mycolors=new HashMap<Integer, String>(){
 {
    //Color constants at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#BLACK
    put(-16777216,"BLACK");
    put(-256,"YELLOW");
    ...and so on... 
 }
};

//Get the color name from your map
String colorname=mycolors.get(Color.parseColor("#"+hexcolor));
//colorname -> YELLOW
```

Otherwise since the above snippet finds the exact match, you could try finding the closest color by using best match algorithm like this one for example: [Best algorithm for matching colours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678457/best-algorithm-for-matching-colours).

Comment: I will try this out and will leave feedback about the success :)

Comment: Thanks, this works. Can you tell me how to get its color name aswell? I tried with this: String colorName= Integer.toString(colorDrawable.getColor()); but it gave back a number not the color's name.

Comment: Isnt there an easier way to do it somehow playing with the objects? Because in my final form of the app I will have about 100+ colors and I have to manage them dynamically (reading their hexcodes from raw file or xml) and with this method Im not able to do it.

Comment: Actually there is no method that gives you back the name of a color.. The only way is defining the colors in a map and find the closest color. -[source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563575/convert-color-integer-to-text)

Comment: Well thanks forthe answer, I will search if I will need this by purpose.