# Implementation of colorgid in magento

Tags: magento

As a part of a project I have to implement a color grid in magento. That is, Users have to find product of a particular color. Users will select a color from the grid and all products of that particular color or similar color will be shown as the output.

I implemented it by extracting and storing dominant colors of a product and retrieving products using an algorithm.

But can't retrieve many products for a color selected by the user. Issue is that we can pass only a single color code (say '#000000') as user selection but color stored in database may be any variant of selected color, so it is not possible to get many products as result.

If anyone implemented such a functionality, please update me with your suggestions.

Comment: Did you see this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678457/best-algorithm-for-matching-colours ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you could use the mysql syntax `CONV(hex_val, 16, 10)` to convert any hexadecimal number such as the color code to a decimal and then select with the between condition, like:

```
SELECT `prod_id` FROM `products` WHERE CONV(`color`, 16, 10) BETWEEN {$color_range_start} AND {$color_range_end}
```

This is from memory and syntax would need to be corrected, but you get the point. After getting the product IDs into an array you could use the standard Magento functions to fetch a product collection based on that.