# Pairing up color names and values

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, colors

I am working on extracting information from figures in scientific papers, combining image processing on the figure itself and natural language processing on its caption.

I have got to a stage where I have isolated objects within the image, and got an "average" colour for each (in both RGB and Lab colorspaces, not sure what's best yet). From the caption, I have parsed a list of objects, along with the color name used to describe them.

So I have two lists:

```
names = ['Red', 'Brown', 'Yellow', 'Magenta'];
rgbs = [ (249,0,252), (253,0,1), (250,248,60), (140,70,20)];
```

I'm trying to figure out an automated method of determining the best pairings between the names and values. Thinking about it, I think it might be best to start by using a lookup table for all common names to convert the names into their "accepted" rgb values. Then I can work out the "distance" (Euclidean?) between each of the rgb values and each of the name rgbs. At this stage somehow I should be able to use those distances to find the optimum pairings, but I'm not sure exactly how.

Does anyone have any ideas, or know of any libraries that might provide useful tools for this?

Comment: some hints here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1678457/989121

Comment: As the parts that are not covered in that question are trivial I guess this counts as a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, I guess if each of the "name rgbs" are nearest to a different rgb value, then I can just pair them up easily. However, I think a more sophisticated pairing algorithm will be needed in case two of the names are closest to the same value. Then I need some way of considering their second-closest values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reading [this work](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/vandeweijer/papers/cvpr07.pdf) it looks like it solves quite a similar problem.

Can you obtain such list pairs ( names - RGB-values ) from **different** figures?
If so, by intersecting these list you may be isolated a color name that is common to a bunch of pairs (only this color) and then try and find the RGB-triplet that is "as-common-as-possible" (up to a little distortion).
You may use this elimination process till you isolate all colors.

For example: suppose you have

```
{ ['Red','Green'], {[1 0 0], [0 1 0]} }
{ ['Red','blue'] , {[.9 .1. 1], [ .2 .3 .9] }
```

You have 'Red' in the intersection, and [1 0 0], [.9 .1 .1] the closest colors.

Comment: Yes, I think the idea of an elimination process is quite a good one. So, first I use a lookup table to convert each color name into its rgb value. Then I find which of these values from the names matches most closely to one of the given rgb values. I pair those up, and eliminate them. Then repeat for the remaining names, until we are done. As for quantifying how closely any two given color values match, I am under the impression that Euclidean distance in Lab colorspace is best.

Comment: @MattSwain Lab with Euclidean distance performs well for similar colors. However, when you compare very different colors color space plays less important a role (see e.g., [this work](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~ofirpele/publications/arXiv2012.pdf))

Answer (score 1):

I happened to need a value->name function as well and found the posts here helpful. This is what I came up with however:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sys 

def squ_diff(c1, c2):
    return ((c1 & 0x0000FF) - (c2 & 0x0000FF))**2 +\
           (((c1 & 0x00FF00)>>8) - ((c2 & 0x00FF00)>>8))**2 +\
           (((c1 & 0xFF0000)>>16) - ((c2 & 0xFF0000)>>16))**2

def best_match(c, ref):
    """Find the best match for color c.
    Uses least square to determine fitness.
    """
    diff = squ_diff(0xFFFFFF, 0x000000)
    best = "None"
    for ref_color in ref:
        curr_diff = squ_diff(c, ref_color[1])
        #if curr_diff < 1000:
        #    print curr_diff, ref_color[0], hex(ref_color[1])
        if curr_diff < diff:
            diff = curr_diff
            best = ref_color[0]
    return best

def get_ref():
    """Retreives some reference colors.
    Format:
        [("red", 0xFF0000), ("green", 0x00FF00), ("blue", 0x0000FF)]
    """
    html = requests.get("http://jadecat.com/tuts/colorsplus.html").content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    return [(e.text[:-6].strip(), int(e.text[-6:], 16)) for e in soup.find_all("td")[2:]]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    """For testing, just provide a hex value as the argument.
    """
    r = get_ref()
    print best_match(int(sys.argv[1], 16), r)
```

It calculates the least squared difference on a given reference table (I just pulled one off the internet) to pair up a name to a given color value. I didn't really do much science insofar as adjusting to human color perception, but what I got works reasonably well. Hopefully this can be useful to someone, as you can modify the scoring function as you please.

The work referenced by Shai is really interesting though, and means that my algorithm should fail on some colors. The idea behind this method however is to give names to as many colors as possible to minimize this effect. You might even map multiple color values to "red", for example.